# Java & Jersey 1.17: Custom default response headers

Tags: java, jersey

I am currently using Java and Jersey 1.17 to create a web service. However, in all the response headers, I always get the current version of whatever web container I am using, such as

```
Content-Type -> application/json
Server -> Jetty(8.1.10.v20130312)
Transfer-Encoding -> chunked
```

is there any way in Jersey to remove the "Server" key-value from the response headers by default, without having to create the Response, remove it manually and then return it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think jersey provides this feature but you can achieve this by writing a Servlet Response Filter.

Learn more about servlet filters here: http://punekaramit.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/intercepting-http-response-using-servlet-filter/

Or read the Oracle docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: Any idea on where to even start with something like that? I've tried looking around the net but can't seem to find anything :S

Comment: @SCassidy1986 follow this: http://punekaramit.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/intercepting-http-response-using-servlet-filter/

Answer (score 0):

Here is tutorial how to use filtering requests and responses in java. [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)

You can use HttpServletResponse.setHeader(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value) 
to set any header you want.

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 0):

Creating such a filter is pretty easy:

```
public class ServerHeaderFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
  private static final String SERVERHEADER = "Server";

  @Override
  public ContainerResponse filter(final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse response)
  {
    response.getHttpHeaders().remove(SERVERHEADER);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, however every response was coming back with the default server header - the only way around this is by setting the server header to an empty String in the filter and returning that, which seems kind of hacky really!